# How to transfer Context to Fragment class

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-context

I've just created a Fragment class. This class is bound to a layout, containing a ListView. Now I wanted to set up an adapter for this ListView, but therefore I need to have some "context".
I could transfer them from the MainActivity class to the Fragment class via the Constructor, but Eclipse tells me not to change the default constructor of a Fragment class. Then I tried to set a

```
public static Context context;
MainActivity.context = this;
```

in the MainActivity class to be able to access this context from anywhere, but again, some errors showed up.

How can I set up an Adapter in my Fragment class?
It looks like this:

```
public static class LatestFragment extends Fragment {
    ListView listView;

    public LatestFragment() {

    }
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_latest, container, false);
        listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.fragment_latest_listview1);

        return rootView;
    }
}
```

As you can see there is the listView which I would like to set up an adapter for. But where should I get the "context" from?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the associated Activity as the context, since Activity is an indirect subclass of Context. You get the Activity inside a Fragment like this:

```
getActivity();
```

Comment: This gives a warning from Android studio as it may produce a 'java.lang.NullPointerException'.

Comment: In some cases getActivity() can return null. You need to check for nullity first before using it. That is what this warning tells you.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Can I check it once and assign it to a variable to use? Or will this give other complications in future?

Comment: It depends on which stage the fragment livecycle is when you call getActivity. Imagine the fragment is currently detached from an activity for example. You are better of checking for nullity before use I would say.